# What is Canopus in this picture?

Tags: star, amateur-observing, photography, night-sky

Picture is taken from 34.2N 126.6E Bogil-do, South Korea. I suppose the dot at up-right side is Rigel and the bright white dot is Sirius, and bright reddish dot at the bottom is light from some fishing boat in the foreground.

Then what is Canopus, of two dots next to fishing boat near the horizon? And what might be the identity of the other dot? (Satellites, airplane etc.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Turning up the contrast to bring out other, fainter stars agrees with your identification of Rigel and Sirius, and makes beta CMa, kappa Ori and epsilon CMa visible.  It also makes it clear that the camera wasn't exactly upright for this image, making the horizon at a slight angle.

The slightly higher dot is in the right position to be Canopus.  If we accept your identification of the reddish dot as a fishing boat, and noting the slight angle of the horizon, the other dots are on, or very close to the horizon.  I suppose that they too are boats, or reflections of boat lights on the water (or a mirage on a warm layer of air that forms over the sea on winter nights)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!